# run bash scripts via a gamepad/joystick on ubuntu-server?

Tags: server, bash, scripts, gamepad, joystick

i have a htpc running ubuntu server 16.04 and i want to plugin a usb gamepad/joystick and and run bash scripts via the buttons.

i googled around i found some tools like qjoypad, that would do that but they all need X server.

is there a way to run bash scripts or simple commands like mpc play/pause via a gamepad/joystick on ubuntu server without x server?

i have neither gamepad or joystick, i would buy one cheap of amazon.
would there be a difference between them? is one or the other preferable?

hope this can be done

Answer (score 0):

i was thinking to complicated, lol

im running kodi on my htpc and i can easily map buttons to a gamepad and run bash scripts via System.Exec.